# What is being compared? GETDATE() - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello I am wondering what gets compared or what the representation of the

```
GETDATE() > 1
```

is in the following line of T-SQL code below.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, CDF_AS_OFDATE, GETDATE()) > 1 )
```

What would happen if I decided to use 100 instead of 1? (I tried it, simply returned a smaller result set).

Answer (score 2):

It's comparing the difference in days between `CDF_AS_OFDATE` and the current date, to see if it's more than 1 day. If you change it to those that have more than 100 days difference, it would most likely be a much smaller result set.

(You can determine it's in days by noticing that it's using `DATEDIFF()` with the `dd` parameter, which indicates you want the difference in days.)

Comment: Oh I see. The numeric values being  compared represents days. Great, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

it check if there was more than 1 day difference between the two date (then vs now)

[SQL Server DATEDIFF() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

The DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates.
Syntax
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)

Where startdate and enddate are valid date expressions and datepart can be one of the following:

```
   day  dd, d
```

Example

Now we want to get the number of days between two dates.

We use the following SELECT statement:
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05') AS DiffDate

Result:
DiffDate
61

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the `DATEDIFF` part of the `WHERE` clause.

It actually evaluates only those rows where the value of `CDF_AS_OFDATE` at least 1 day different from the current system date.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start...

**In your first example...**

```
where getdate() > 1
```

First `getdate()` returns the current date and time-of-day as a `datetime` value. If you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), you'll discover that (1) there is no implicit conversion from `datetime` to `int`, but there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `datetime`. That means the expression is pretty much identical to

```
where getdate() > convert(datetime,1)
```

The epoch (zero point) of the SQL Server calendar is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`, which is what you get if you say `convert(datetime,0)` or `convert(datetime,'')`. When you convert an `int` value to a `datetime` value, the integer value is taken to indicate an offset in days since the epoch. The conversion is performed by adding that many days to the epoch to get the resulting `datetime` value: `convert(datetime,1)` thus yields the `datetime` value `1900-01-02 00:00:00.000` and your expression is thus the equivalent of

```
where getdate() > '1900-01-02 00:00:00.000'
```

which expression will always be true unless you've seriously mucked with your systems clock.

**In your second example...**

```
where datediff( dd , CDF_AS_OF_DATE , getdate() ) > 1
```

- `getdate()` as noted earlier gives you the current date and time-of-day.
- datediff() returns the delta between two `datetime` values in the requested units of time. If you want to be pedantic about things (and I do), depending on the unit requested, the resulting value is not necessarily correct (depend on your definition of "correct"): what you get is the count of unit boundaries between the two `datetime` values. So even though exactly one second separates the two `datetime` values in the expression below,

  - `datediff(dd,'Dec 31, 2013 23:59:59','Jan 1, 2014 00:00:00')` returns `1` indicating a delta of 1 day, whilst
  - `datediff(year,'Dec 31, 2013 23:59:59','Jan 1, 2014, 00:00:00') likewise returns`1` indicating a delta of 1 year.

So your `where` clause is restricting the result set to rows where the delta (in days) from the as-of date to the current date/time is greater than 1.